# Use Configuration File with Stand-Alone C# exe

Tags: c#, configuration, exe, app-config

I have developed a C# application based on the .NET framework in Visual Studio and have created a supplemental "App.config" file which I use to define certain variables in my Main.

Within Visual Studio, the config file seems to work fine and uses ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("name") to define variables.

When I compile the application to a separate .exe and place it in the same directory as the "App.config" file, however, it fails to define the variables using the config file.

Is there any way to have a stand-alone executable that pulls information from the config file? How should it be set up?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Before compiling your solution, in `File Explorer` of Visual Studio, right click your `App.config` file and select `Properties`.

On `Build Action` property of the file, set it as `Embedded Resource`.

On `Copy to Output Directory` property of the file, set it as `Copy always`.

Build your solution on Release and give it a try, hope it helps.

Comment: No luck with that unfortunately. Is there any simple way to attach a config file to an .exe? I am thinking I can just compile the "application.cs" in visual studio's developer command prompt and attach it somehow. It's a very simple application.

Comment: I think there is not. By the way, if the name of your app is "MyApp" the actual file you want to use is "MyApp.exe.config" which is the file from where your "MyApp.exe" retrieves your settings, keys and values, etc.